# Looking for orders that weren't billed for certain services

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm trying to query our database to find all jobs were certain services were provided, but have orders where those products were not billed. I've tried putting this together multiple ways, but I just can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. This is basically what I'm looking for:

```
declare @startDate datetime = '1/01/2018';
declare @endDate datetime = '2/28/2018';

select o.orderid
from orders as o
left join orderitem as oi on oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
left join job as j on j.JobID = o.JobID
left join jobservice as js on js.JobID = j.JobID
where oi.ProductID not in ('55', '65', '78')
and js.ServiceID in ('13', '16')
and o.ShippedToClientID = j.ClientID
and j.JobDate between @startDate and @endDate + 1
and o.IsVoided = '0'
group by o.orderid
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide more detail on the mysteries of what services you want and the rules for them.  Your query is way more complicated than your explanation.

Comment: You forgot to provide a schema description, example data and expected results for the example data. You also forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I will try to clarify.  A job can have one or more of 14 services assigned to it.  I'm specifically looking for jobs with only 2 of the 14 services.

Each job can have multiple orders assigned to it, but out of the original results, I only want to find orders that do not bill for specific products.  The Orders table does not have the line items for products, that is why I join in the OrderItems table.  I am using the o.ShippedToClientID = j.ClientID statement to only find orders for the same firm that originally scheduled the job.  Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `not exists`.  Something like this:

```
select o.orderid
from orders o
where not exists (select 1
                  from orderitem oi join 
                       job j
                       on j.JobID = o.JobID join
                       jobservice js
                       on js.JobID = j.JobID
                   where oi.OrderID = o.OrderID and
                         o.ShippedToClientID = j.ClientID and
                         oi.ProductID not in (55, 65, 78) and
                         js.ServiceID in (13, 16) and
                         j.JobDate between @startDate and @endDate + 1 and
                         o.IsVoided = 0
                  );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to limit the results to only those specific services.